# How do I efficiently locate key-value pairs in a multi-dimensional PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have an array in PHP as a result of the following query to a Wordpress database:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = :id
```

I am returned a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [meta_id] => 380 [post_id] => 72 [meta_key] => _edit_last       [meta_value] => 1 )
```

... etc.

What is the best way to find a particular key-value pair in this array?

For instance, how would I located the row where `[meta_key]` = event_name so that I can extract that same row's `[meta_value]` value into a PHP variable?

I realize I could turn this into many individual MySQL queries.  Does anyone have an opinion of the efficiency of doing 10 SQL queries in a row rather than searching the array 10 times?  I would think since the array is in memory, that will be the fastest method to find the values I need.

Alternatively, is there a better way to query the database from the beginning so that my result set is formatted in a way that is easier to search?

Comment: Actually, `mysql_query()` will return a MySQL **Resource**, not an array. You have to use the MySQL functions (such as `mysql_fetch_array`) to get through the results.

Comment: Do you build the result array yourself or do you just get it back from a Wordpress function?

Comment: I'm using PHP PDO to query so I can use parameters.  I'm not sure what the underlying code looks like, but a call to pdo->fetchAll() returns a multidimensional array that is both numerically and associatively indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you always want to search for the columns "meta_key" creating the array you could do something like this:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr[$row['meta_key']] = $row;
}
```

Then you will have a associative array the the value of "meta_key" as the primary index. But in this case the "meta_key" has to be unique as otherwise you would overwrite the values.

Your example would than look like this:

```
Array ( [_edit_last] => Array ( [meta_id] => 380, [post_id] => 72, [meta_key] => _edit_last, [meta_value] => 1 )
```

And you can easily get the "meta_value" by using the index:

```
$var = $arr['_edit_last']['meta_value'];
```

Is that what you wanted to have?

**EDIT**: If you have mor than one value per "meta_key" you could also create a multidimensional array for each key. Just use this line within the while loop instead:

```
$arr[$row['meta_key']][] = $row;
```

You will than have an array for each row per "meta_value" so your array might look like this:

```
Array ( [_edit_last] => Array ( [0] => Array( [meta_id] => 380, [post_id] => 72, [meta_key] => _edit_last, [meta_value] => 1 ) )
```

You can then use another loop to get all values from a group of "meta_key" values.

Comment: Also Kyle, you're correct that searching the array 10 times is probably faster than 10 mysql queries.  But it might not be as much of a difference as you'd guess.

Comment: From my tests, there's absolutely nothing wrong with looping with `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Running queries in a loop, however, are quite slow in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the array you gave, do the following:

```
$multiArray = Array ( [0] => Array ( ['meta_id'] => 380, ['post_id'] => 72, ['meta_key'] => _edit_last, ['meta_value'] => 1 );
$needleKey = 'meta_key';
$needle = 'event_name';

foreach ($multiArray as $key => $data) {
    if ($data[$needleKey] == $needle) {
        echo $key;
        break;
    }
}
```